# After mining litecoins for about two hours, how long will it take for anything to go into my account?

Tags: litecoin, cgminer

I've been mining now for about two hours. How long would it take for anything to appear in my account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long to earn fractions of bitcoin](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20753/how-long-to-earn-fractions-of-bitcoin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/in-the-asic-age-is-it-worth-starting-mining-bitcoin-at-home)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a lot of things including what kind GPU's you are using and if you are pooled mining or mining with the main client. If you are solo mining with a GPU you will most likely not see anything for a very long time or at all. You can use this to determine how much you would make mining with a pool https://www.litecoinpool.org/calc. I don't mine litecoins myself but it seems that https://www.wemineltc.com is a popular pool for people who do.

Answer (score 0):

Most cryptocoins require 120 confirmations (additional blocks added to the chain) before the block reward is granted. I'm not sure about [Litecoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litecoin), but if that's the case, and if you are solo mining, or if your pool doesn't take any chances, the first reward will be 120 confirmations after the first mined block.

And since blocks are mined about every 2.5 minutes, that's about 5 hours.